# Invoking PUT request multiple times

Tags: rest

I am trying to access a REST enpoint that adds a book in bookshelf location.

```
PUT /bookshelf/books/1

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
```

Now if I try to add book again with id 1

```
PUT /bookshelf/books/1

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal server error
```

I get 500 Internal server error, with the response message

```
 "Resource already exists, cannot add duplicate item"
```

Now this looks wrong to me. Is this a right kind of response to expect from the server. Considering the operation is PUT, I feel the clients should feel free to run the PUT invocations to do again and again. Is my understanding correct?

If not `500` should the server just return `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`?

Answer (score 1):

PUT is idempotent - if you call it multiple times you should get the same result. i.e. the object is created/updated as per your request. Returning 500 to a PUT request because the object already exists goes against RESTful semantics. I would also expect 200 back in this instance.